# Voip sample Application Error -> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

Tags: visual-c++, voip

I am upgrade my 32 bit sample Voip application to 64 bit. After upgrade my application .exe file give a problem:

> **The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)**

My PC is 64 bit. and i build it in 64 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is probably late for you, but for anybody looking at this question, the problem is that you have a mixture of 32-bit and 64-bit components (DLLs) that are loaded at start-up.  Since your app is built as 64-bit, you probably still have some 32-bit DLLs that the system attempts to load in the process and fails (since 32-bit modules cannot be loaded in a 64-bit process).